# Counting distinct values with overlapping time windows

Tags: sql, teradata

I am working in Teradata 15, my data looks like this:
table1 (userid, activitydate, activitytype)

and I am being asked to calculate the unique users within the 30 day period ending every Saturday. So psuedo code would look like:

```
select count(distinct(userid)
from table1 
where activitydate between Saturday and Saturday - 30
```

which is all good except I need to return a value for every Saturday, and I need to do this using interactive SQL, no compiled UDF's, procedures or looping.

The ideal results would look like:

weekending  uniqueusers

4/7/18       10000

4/14/18      15000

I have read lots of posts about row numbers and multiple levels of CTE's but I cant manage to get what I need. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Teradata's PERIOD data type and the `Sys_calendar.Calendar` table to put this together:

```
WITH saturdays AS (
    SELECT PERIOD(calendar_date - INTERVAL '30' DAY, NEXT(calendar_date)) AS sat_period
    FROM Sys_Calendar."CALENDAR" 
    WHERE calendar_date BETWEEN DATE '2018-01-01' AND CURRENT_DATE
        AND day_of_week = 7
)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) count_of_users, 
    END(sat_period) AS saturday_Date
FROM yourtable
    INNER JOIN saturdays ON 
        saturdays.sat_period CONTAINS yourtable.datefield
GROUP BY saturday_date
```

Run just that CTE by itself and you'll see what's happening there. We're basically just constructing a date PERIOD from the sys_calendar for the current year (change that date range as you see fit). The PERIOD in teradata is up to, but not including the end date in the range, so we bump it by one day with the `NEXT()` function.

Once the periods are constructed from the sys_calendar table we can INNER JOIN that back to your table and aggregate.